# Linux GCC Compiler Output in Mint: What to do with the file?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-mint

I wrote a simple c program. saved it with "c" suffix. Went to the terminal (in Linux Mint), typed in

```
gcc -o outputfile inputfile.c
```

In the directory containing inputfile.c a file called outputfile appeared, as I expected. I want to run the program, but clicking on the file does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it do something if you type `./outputfile` at the command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is running, but you're not seeing its output because the terminal isn't open. Open up your terminal and run it with ./outputfile

If your program opened a window, you would see it by clicking on the file.